# How to resolve Error in `gargle::response_process()

Tags: r, drive

I'm trying to log in with my drive account from R, but when I try I get the following error.

```
Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
Error in `gargle::response_process()`:
! Client error: (403) Forbidden
Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
• domain: global
• reason: insufficientPermissions
• message: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/gargle_error_request_failed>
Error in `gargle::response_process()`:
! Client error: (403) Forbidden
Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
• domain: global
• reason: insufficientPermissions
• message: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
---
Backtrace:
  1. googledrive::drive_ls(path = ruta[1, 1])
  2. googledrive:::as_parent(path)
  4. googledrive:::as_dribble.character(d)
  8. googledrive::drive_get(path = x)
 10. purrr::map(as_id(id), get_one_file_id)
 11. googledrive (local) .f(.x[[i]], ...)
 12. gargle::response_process(response)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
>
```

I have looked for a way to solve this error and I have not found

Comment: Answer to similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356212/client-doesnt-have-sufficient-permission